# Designig a website for academic scholar audiences

Tags: gui-design, human-interface-guideline

I am a Software Engineering student and I was designing a website for my university Mining Engineering department that gives information about rocks. This website is going to be maintained by them meaning they will insert data about the rocks so I have to design both the user side and admin side of the project.

I suspect that the admin users are not very savvy with updating websites, and would like to create a good experience for them. How might I approach getting started with this?

Answer (score 1):

Ask them if you can :-)

Fairly generically:

Ask (requirements, data , user type),
Build (Use Nielsen's usability guidelines along with your requirements),
Test (find errors / misconceptions)
Fix
Loop till happy

But honestly, there won't be many academics in an engineering dept who aren't experienced with computers. They'll use university admin systems for all kinds of data entry: student systems - research grant systems - long term data storage - paper submissions - teaching allocations - room allocations - etc etc etc - none of them will just be solely out in the field chipping rocks - might be a good idea to have a look at some of those systems if you don't have time/access to do the user-centred design/develop/test cycle (and as someone who worked at a university most of them will give you ideas of what not to do more than anything else :-) )

PS I would also say that as someone who built a data entry system for biologists that edge case billy's will be the bane of your life so be prepared for them. "Here's a nice dropdown for the type of rock." "Ah, but what if I want to say it's two rocks stuck together of different types?" "Agh"

Answer (score 0):

I would start with some user interviews and observation sessions. Find out things like:

- Do they have any experience with updating websites? (Have they ever used something like Drupal, Wordpress, Sharepoint, anything at all?)
- What other tech tools do they use during their day to get their work done, and how is that going for them? Google Docs, SurveyMonkey, academia-specific systems?
- Which tools do they like using, and why? What about those tools is going well?
- Which tools do they not like using, and why not? What do you need to avoid when you build a system for them? If they mention something being "not user friendly", ask if you can have them pull up the system and watch them do some tasks on it. Dig in!
- What is this system replacing?

Once you have a basic understanding of their technical level and capabilities, you can use that in developing a [persona](https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/user-research/putting-personas-to-work-in-ux-design/), which will inform how you build.

Next, you can gather the requirements - what are the users' goals and objectives? You can create [journey maps](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/journey-mapping-101/) to map out the steps your admins are going to take. (How are they doing this kind of data cataloging work today? And how would they do it in the future using your system?)

Once you have a good idea of the workflow, you can [create wireframes](https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/wireframing/wireframe-design-101/) for each step. Be careful with this, sometimes academic audiences don't understand that wireframes are representational. If you show them to some users and find that they're struggling to understand them, you might need to build a more realistic prototype. (If you don't have a prototyping tool like Figma or it's quicker to just build this out in Drupal or whatever system you're using, by all means, go ahead and do that.)

Watch your users work with your designs, and keep iterating on anything that's a struggle or point of confusion for them.